# Missing points in Persistent Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, topological-data-analysis

I'm working on a project with a professor. This project involves Persistent Homology methods over a point cloud. Recently we found some inconsistencies in the point clouds that we were reading, especifically, some points were missing. The amount of missing points is about 5% of the total and I wanted to know how badly this could impact the precision of the results.

I understand Persistent Homology is robust, but I don't know to what extent.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with persistent homology, but I'm pretty sure it depends on where exactly the points were. If they existed inside dense clusters of points, their absence will not have much of an effect. However, if they were part of a cycle it could cause the cycle to be detected later than it would otherwise. If they were in the middle of what is now a cycle, their absence could make it look like that cycle persists longer than it should. All in all, 5% doesn't seem like that much, but I don't know your data.